# Batch para eleger letra de drive

Tags: batch

Estou criando um menu para *deploy* de imagens via *winpe*. Dentro deste eu rodo alguns comandos e aplico em arquivos que ficam guardados num HD externo.

Eu até consegui fazer um `if exist c:\IMG GOTO` e daí prosseguir com o *script*, mas como as letras podem variar muito, o *script* fica imenso.

Existe alguma forma de atribuir um valor a uma variável através de uma condição, algo como:

```
If exist C:\IMG então VAR=C
```

E daí aplicar os comandos como sendo `VAR:\IMG\image.wim`

Eu gostaria que a variável no caso correspondesse a letra do drive que contem a pasta *IMG*.

Comment: Você quer percorrer todas os drives e verificar se existe a pasta IMG na raiz?

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o comando [`SET`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) para definir uma variável e com [`EXIST`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) você verifica se um arquivo ou pasta existe.

```pascal
SET "LETRA="                 :: Declara a variável que vai receber a letra do drive

if exist C:\ (               :: Se existir
 SET LETRA=C:\               :: Coloca a letra do drive na variável LETRA
) else (                     :: Se não encontrar
 echo Arquivo nao encontrado
 PAUSE
 EXIT /B
)
echo %LETRA%IMG\image.wim    :: Exibe o caminho da imagem se existir
```

Se você tiver a necessidade de verificar muitas vezes se um arquivo/diretório é existente, automatizar esse processo numa função pode poupar algumas linhas de código:

```pascal
SET "LETRA="                 :: Declara a variável que vai receber a letra do drive
call :ElegerDrive c:\        :: Chama "ElegerDrive" com um argumento, no caso c:\

:ElegerDrive
IF EXIST %~1 (               :: Se o arquivo ou pasta existir
   SET LETRA=%~1             :: Atribui a variável LETRA o argumento
   GOTO :FIM                
) ELSE (
   echo O drive %~1 nao foi encontrado.
   PAUSE
   EXIT /B
)
:Fim
echo %LETRA%IMG\image.wim
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode usr o **`mountvol`** para obter os **drivers montados no sistema** já movendo para uma **variável** e usá-la num looping **`for`** para verificar a existência da pasta em cada driver montado via **`findstr`**, e, caso positivo, setar sua variável....

```ps1
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & cls & echo/

for /f "tokens=*delims= " %%f in ('mountvol^|find /i ":\"')do set _drv=!_drv!, %%f
echo/ Procurando nos drivers: !_drv:~1! & for %%f in (!_drv:~1!)do 2>nul dir %%fIMG /ad|^
findstr /il %%fIMG>nul && echo/ && set "_IMG=%%fIMG" && echo/ Localizado em: !_IMG!
```

---

> **Ou** um pouco mais simples...

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

```ps1
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & cls & echo/

for /f "tokens=*delims= " %%f in ('mountvol^|find /i ":\"')do 2>nul dir %%fIMG /ad |^
findstr /il %%fIMG>nul && (echo/ & set "_IMG=%%fIMG" & echo/Localizado: !_IMG! & echo/)
```

---